# What pre-processing does VADER sentiment analysis use?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, lemmatization, vader

I read that VADER performs tokenization / lemmatization automatically when you use `SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()` but I cannot get a clear confirmation on their [github](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment) page. I tried tokenize and lemmatize my input text anyways and the outputs (compound scores) are identical than if I didn't do any of my own pre-processing.

Can anyone confirm what pre-processing techniques they use?

Thank you.